# A valid react element or null must be returned. react-redux connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I had this component:

```
let Vepo = (props) => (
  <Container >
    <Header style={styles.header}>
      <Left>
        <Button transparent>
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.title}>Search</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
      </Right>
    </Header>
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView >
        <Keywords />
        <Categories />
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  </Container>
)

Vepo = connect(
  null,
  null
)(Vepo)

export default Vepo
```

But now I need to implement `ComponentDidMount` so going by [this example of using a higher order component](https://github.com/JamieDixon/react-lifecycle-component):

```
    class Wrapper extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.getAllTehDatas();
        }

        render() {
            <WrappedComponent {..this.props} />
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = () => ({

    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = {
        getAllTehDatas
    };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Wrapper);
```

I should be able to do this:

```
let Vepo = (props) => (
  <Container >
    <Header style={styles.header}>
      <Left>
        <Button transparent>
        </Button>
      </Left>
      <Body>
        <Title style={styles.title}>Search</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right>
      </Right>
    </Header>
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView >
        <Keywords />
        <Categories />
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  </Container>
)

class Wrapper extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("loaded")
    }

    render() {
        <Vepo />
    }
}

Vepo = connect(
  null,
  null
)(Wrapper)

export default Vepo
```

But I am getting this error:

> Wrapper.render(): A valid react element or null must be returned. You
>   may have returned undefined, and array of some other object.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: may i ask, what the second null is for? i have one connect(

mapStateToProps,

null     --- and wondered if this is to unsuscribe from mapDispatchToProps and why would i want that

Answer (score 0):

It is about the render of *Wrapper*, you dropped return for it. Change render to this:

```js
render() {
    return <Vepo/>
}
```